# In matrix product, differentiate one element with respect to another element

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory, matrix-equations, differential-calculus

**Background**

Consider a system (roughly) along the lines of those shown in [Sims, C. A. (2002). Solving linear rational expectations models](http://sims.princeton.edu/yftp/gensys/LINRE3A.pdf), where you have

$$ AX_{t+1} = CX_t + M $$

where matrix $M$ is a constant. We can assume $M = 0$ for the time being. Note that matrices $A$ and $C$ may be singular.

While the dimensions and values of the matrices can be arbitrary, here's an example for the $3 \times 3$ case.

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & \alpha & 3\\
0 & 11 & 5\\
-1 & \beta & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad 
C = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 & 7\\
2.2 & 9 & 5\\
2 & 0.2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad
X_t = \begin{bmatrix}
4\\
2\\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Imagine we have found a matrix $B$ that gives us a solution for $X_{t+1}$ of the form

$$ X_{t+1} = BX_t$$

($B$ may have been computed numerically, if an analytic expression is difficult). We therefore have

$$ ABX_t = CX_t $$
and
$$ AB = C $$

**The Question**

Say we perturb one element of $A$ (e.g. $A \rightarrow A + \Delta_{kl}$, with $\Delta_{kl}$ being a matrix of zeros for all elements except for element $k,l$ with takes a small positive value $\delta$), what effect does this have on the value of an element $B_{ij}$ of matrix $B$?

If $(k,l)=(1,2)$ this is basically asking for $ \partial B_{ij} / \partial \alpha$ in the example above.

Is it possible to derive an expression for this quantity? (and not just use a numerical solver)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've added more detail, and a link to the paper that is somewhat related to the problem (although it does not ask the same question I am asking)